# Cucumber Table Diff and colspan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

I love cucumber, and its table diff feature.  But I, often use a td colspan to display the title of the table.  And I can't seem to get the table diff to work when I use colspan. (Table diff expects a 2d array, and the colspan breaks it)

Has anyone be able to get this to work.

Thanks!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of cucumber introduced the [tablish](http://rdoc.info/github/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails/master/Cucumber/Web/Tableish) function -- which very elegantly solves this problem

Answer (score 1):

The tableish method has been deprecated https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/commit/3baebac3885c754ea0d626693441603471479ded

Answer (score 0):

Can you use comments? For example:

```
Then the user should have these friends:
  # Friend List
  | Mike | Nicholaides | Best-Friend |
  | John | Stamos      | OK-Friend   |
```

Comment: That did not work for me, I got a Cucumber::Parser::Syntax error.
But I like your syntax, I would have loved if that worked.

`Parse error, expected one of "\n", "\r", "#", "Given", "When", "Then", "And", "But", "@", "Scenario", "Scenario Outline". (Cucumber::Parser::SyntaxError)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than **1** feature in one of your feature file?

Cucumber dose not allow it and would raise the `Parse error`.